# Query Apple TV for currently playing media information

Tags: http, protocols, apple-tv

Newbie question regarding querying an Apple TV. 
Not really sure where to start so any advice is welcome!

What I am trying to do, is query what is playing and get info like:

- Filename
- Media Meta data
- Media Length
- Media Current position
- Media Icon image

Across varies apps such as:

- Netflix
- Infuse

Do I need to work out a how to communicate to each of those apps individually? Is that even possible?
Or is there some global 'playing now' Apple API which I can query for the info?

Thanks

Comment: You want to query this information from within your own application, correct?

Comment: Yes, I have a C# windows forms app which should do the polling/querying